# Yii model rules "Failed to set unsafe attribute"

Tags: php, yii

I've looking but can't get It to work.

These are my rules in model Acta.php

```
public function rules()
{
    return array(
        array('dominio', 'required'),
        array('numero, velocidad, grupo, dni, cuit, plan_pago_id', 'numerical', 'integerOnly'=>true),
        array('foto, observaciones, situacion, infractor, dominio, tipo_vehiculo, marca, modelo, domicilio, codigo_postal, localidad, provincia, tipo_multa, usuario', 'length', 'max'=>255),
        array('hora', 'length', 'max'=>11),

        //Here is the problem with only this three attributes
        array('municipio, cinemometro, fecha_labrada', 'safe', 'on'=> 'create,update'),

        // The following rule is used by search().
        // @todo Please remove those attributes that should not be searched.
        array('id, numero, fecha_labrada, velocidad, grupo, foto, observaciones, situacion, infractor, dominio, dni, cuit, tipo_vehiculo, marca, modelo, domicilio, codigo_postal, localidad, provincia, tipo_multa, hora, usuario, plan_pago_id', 'safe', 'on'=>'search'),
    );
}
```

And this is the code on controller ActaController.php

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    $model = new Acta;

    if(isset($_POST['Acta']))
    {

        ...
        code setting data on $_POST['Acta']
        ...

        $model->attributes = $_POST['Acta'];
        $model->save();
    }

    $this->redirect(array('ingresar'));

}
```

I can't see the problem. Should be working right?

**EDIT:**
I thought that the scenario was set automatically. I was wrong.
To fix this the scenario must be set before the attributes:

```
...
$model->setScenario('create');
$model->attributes = $_POST['Acta'];
...
```

Comment: have you set all the attributes you are mass assigning to 'safe'?

Comment: @themosquitokiller what do you mean? like for testing something as `array('... all attributes ...', 'safe'),` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Before you save, You absolutely have some errors. To be aware about errors do like below:

```
if($model->validate()){
    //NO ERRORS, SO WE PERFORM SAVE PROCESS
    $model->save()
}else{
    //TO SEE WHAT ERROR YOU HAVE
    CVarDumper::dump($model->getErrors(),56789,true);
    Yii::app()->end();
    //an alternative way is to show attribute errors in view
}
```

On the other hand, it seems you set some attributes as `safe` on specific scenarios. But you did not set the `scenario`.

to set scenario, do like below:

```
$model->setScenario('THE SCENARIO NAME');
```

Or:

```
$model=new YOURMODELNAME('SCENARIO NAME');
```

I hope it help

Comment: Thank you. I did tried setting the scenario but I was doing It in the wrong place (after setting the attributes). And now on I'll use the validation before saving, as you recommended.

Comment: The scenarios! This answer set me on the right path to solving a similar unsafe attribute error.